# Delete all the digits from a string except the digits that are followed by given letter using re.sub() in python3

Tags: python, python-re

I know how to remove all digits from a string using `re.sub()`. But I don't know how to remove all digits from a string except some special ones.

For example, let's say I have the string below:

```
"On 11 December 2008, India entered the 3G arena"
```

And I want the output as:

```
"On December, India entered the 3G arena"
```

Comment: Well, the first step is to put into words what you mean by "some special ones". Then you, or someone helping, can work out how to translate that description into a form that a computer will understand. It's also helpful (for yourself, and for others helping you) to come up with both a list of examples that you want to remove, *and* a list of examples you *don't* want to remove, so that solutions can be tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `Negative Lookahead (?!...)` to ensure that content following the digit is not a letter you set

Here an example where all digits followed by any of there char `GJK` are not concerned by the suppression

```
import re

print(re.sub(r"\d(?![GJK])", "", "On 11 December 2008, India entered the 3G arena 1A 3J 5K"))
# On  December , India entered the 3G arena A 3J 5K
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use `\b` (word boundary) to delete numbers which are not apparently part of words, following way:

```
import re
txt = "On 11 December 2008, India entered the 3G arena"
cleaned = re.sub(r'\b \d+\b','',txt)
print(cleaned)
```

Output:

```
On December, India entered the 3G arena
```

Note that there is space before \d+ as otherwise you would end with doubled spaces. This solution assumed that digits to remove are always after space, if this does not hold true you might use `r'\b\d+\b'` and then remove superflouos spaces.

Comment: Doesn't remove the number from `'In December, 31 days are cold.'`.

Answer (score 0):

While [azro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65372925/3944322) covers the general case, here's a solution to remove numbers around month names:

```
import calendar
month_names = '|'.join([calendar.month_name[i] for i in range(1,13)])

s = "On 11 December 2008, India entered the 3G arena"

re.sub(fr"\d+\s+({month_names})\s+\d+", r"\1", s)
#'On December, India entered the 3G arena'
```